# instantiate COM object fail Unable to cast object

Tags: c#, com

I have a COM object created with C# .net framework 2.0, the COM client a windows application  net framework 4.6.1. 
COM client fail to  instantiate COM object, the exception is - Unable to cast object.
By setting useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy in the COM client app.config to false, instantiate COM object successful.

Can you please explain this?
is there a way that we instantiate COM object with useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy  set to true?

Code for COM object we took from :
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35532/C-COM-Object-for-Use-In-JavaScript-HTML-Including

We replace the client with windows application.

[fail casting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Uj9k.png)

[registry com object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D1uC.png)

Comment: It's very dependent on your project specifics. Difficult to say w/o more information/reproducing code, etc. Note that useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy default value is in fact false. So, IMHO you should instead work at keeping useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy to false instead of changing everything to be able to set it to true. Can't you just recompile your framework 2 component and move forward future-proof?

Comment: I recompiled the com object on 4.6.1 when the client set useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"   the same error casting happen

Comment: If everything is compiled with 4.6.1, you don't need useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy at all.

Comment: Hmm, this stuff does not add up to make any sense.  Just stop using COM, it isn't useful at all in this scenario.  Don't add a reference to the type library, add a reference to the assembly instead.  And use the `new` keyword to create the instance, just like you always do with a .NET class.  Whether the class library was compiled to target 2.0 or 4.6.1 does not matter.

Comment: This is  a POC to trouble shoot a problem that we have in our product.Our product consume a com object from third party, currently we found out that if we compiled or product on 32 bit, we dont fail with casting where our product is WPF application with the configuration of useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy set true

Answer (score 0):

You can read about setting the V2 runtime activation policy at run-time here: http://reedcopsey.com/2011/09/15/setting-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-at-runtime/